# Surface Pro - Disable Wifi?

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-8, microsoft-surface

I recently purchased a Surface pro for one of our executive users (at their request.)  I have successfully deployed our image to it, joined it to our domain, etc.  When using the USB Ethernet adapter, it logs on to our network after putting in domain credentials, with no issue.  However, we do not authenticate domain users over WiFi.  The behavior present at this point, is when attempting to login, it no doubt tries to authenticate with the server, but cannot access it through WiFi.  Ever with the domain account cached, it takes about 6 minutes for it to finish logging in.

Compare this with a wired connection, it takes 5 seconds.

Our normal resolution (with every other device with WiFi) is to disable WiFi if there is no enet connection available.  Thus forcing the machine to go right for the cached account.  Once logged in, turn WiFi back on, and have it connect to the local access point.

**Problem**:  There doesn't seem to be a way using the keyboard, or standard login screen, to disable WiFi on the Surface for pre-login.

Does anyone know a special key combination, or trick to be able to disable WiFi from the login screen of the Microsoft Surface Pro?

Comment: Does the Wifi connection have the LAN's AD DNS server as it's (first) DNS entry? Have you tried adjusting the network adapter binding order, so that the wired connection is checked first?

Comment: @techie007 - Im not sure what you mean.  Any more light you can share on that topic, please do.

Comment: [How can I change the binding order of network adapters in Windows 7?](http://superuser.com/questions/117507/how-can-i-change-the-binding-order-of-network-adapters-in-windows-7)

Comment: Plus re-check my comment for the question about DNS entries. If the AD's DNS server isn't (first) in your list, then you'll get LONG login times, and possibly never fully connect to the domain (controller) :)

Comment: @techie007 I have verified that it is not in there.  However we are in a very very complicated network.  Im hoping there may be a way to force the wifi to turn off prior to being logged in to...

Answer (score 1):

On Windows 8.1, you should simply be able to disable it by tapping the signal logo on the login screen on the bottom left corner.

[image]

[image]