# Adding WiFi network causes domain network to become unresponsive

Tags: windows, networking

Setup: Notebook PC running Windows 7 Pro with a wired Ethernet connection to a Domain network and a WiFi connection to a 'home network router'. 
The Router is then connected to a WiFi device. The Domain network uses a 10.x.x.x IP address while the 'home network router' uses a 192.68.0.x
IP Address. The Domain network is our regular corporate network for E-mail, Internet etc. The 'home network router' uses DHCP. But the 
'home network router' does NOT have WAN link or Internet connection i.e. it is a closed private network with the sole intent of connecting 
the PC to a specific WiFi device.

We're able to talk to the 'WiFi device', no problem. However, as soon as we have connected to the WiFi network or connected to the 'home network router'
via an ethernet cable, the domain network becomes unresponsive or very slow to respond. Starting up Visual Studio takes a while (presumably it's phoning 
home over the network). Starting up the Chrome Web Browser usually fails. Chrome shows the message "DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NO_INTERNET". It would appear that 
these applications are trying to connect to the internet via the 'home network router' not via the domain. If I browse through network configurations 
in Windows it's obvious that this 'home network' does not have an internet connection while domain connection is clearly stating that internet access is 
available. If I disable the WiFi network Chrome etc behaves OK.

How can I change my setup, so that I don't have to unplug or disable the 'home network'?

Comment: You'll need to adjust the NIC priority for the LAN to take precedence over WiFi: http://superuser.com/questions/708716/set-lan-to-take-network-priority-before-wi-fi-on-windows-7 ..

Answer (score 0):

Changed the IP properties for the 'home network' to use a static IP address and changed the 'Default gateway' ip address empty. (That was the only way I could find to undefine the original default gateway settings). Now Chrome works and Visual Studio etc.