# Windows 7 Routing Prioritizes WLAN

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, routing

I'm currently at a loss. I've tried to Google and also searched through this place, but nothing I do seems to work.

When I have both my LAN and WLAN enabled, the WLAN is taking priority. I have a web server hosted on the LAN located at 192.168.5.118. When WLAN is active, I cannot access this web server as the traffic is being routed through the WLAN. If I disable the WLAN, I am able to access the web server successfully.

I have followed [topics such as this](https://superuser.com/questions/708716/set-lan-to-take-network-priority-before-wi-fi-on-windows-7). Setting up the WLAN metric to 9999 and flushing out the routing table before rebooting. No success.

I have also changed the binding [as indicated in this Microsoft KB](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2526067). Again, no success. Besides disabling my WLAN (which means I will no longer be able to access the web), I cannot figure out a solution.

Here is the routing table for further information.

```
C:\Windows\system32>route print
===========================================================================
Interface List
 11...5c 26 0a 4b 13 90 ......Intel(R) 82577LM Gigabit Network Connection
 12...18 3d a2 20 0e 6c ......Intel(R) Centrino(R) Advanced-N 6200 AGN
  1...........................Software Loopback Interface 1
 17...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter
 15...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface
 19...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #2
 18...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #3
===========================================================================

IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0       172.22.0.2    172.22.17.104  19998
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
       172.22.0.0      255.255.0.0         On-link     172.22.17.104  10255
    172.22.17.104  255.255.255.255         On-link     172.22.17.104  10255
   172.22.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     172.22.17.104  10255
      192.168.0.0      255.255.0.0         On-link     192.168.5.220    266
    192.168.5.220  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.5.220    266
  192.168.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.5.220    266
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link     192.168.5.220    266
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link     172.22.17.104  10255
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.5.220    266
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     172.22.17.104  10255
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  None

IPv6 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
 If Metric Network Destination      Gateway
  1    306 ::1/128                  On-link
  1    306 ff00::/8                 On-link
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  None
```

IP Configuration.

```
C:\Windows\system32>ipconfig

Windows IP Configuration


Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.5.220
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.0.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :

Wireless LAN adapter Wireless Network Connection:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : wtccorp.com
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 172.22.17.104
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.0.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 172.22.0.2

Tunnel adapter isatap.{C07E68D9-80F9-4D79-88F5-6506A3F93A2C}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Tunnel adapter Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Tunnel adapter isatap.wtccorp.com:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : wtccorp.com

Tunnel adapter isatap.{F0B16D61-44D7-44FD-99BF-256864A20C13}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
```

Comment: whats your ipconfig result?

Comment: @boboes - Added ipconfig to main post.

Comment: Whatever your default route may be, your computer will answer requests on the same interface, if that interface has a route back.

Comment: @quickblueblur How about you put an entry in HOSTS file ?

Comment: why does `192.168.5.220` has this network mask `255.255.0.0` and not `255.255.255.0`? Could you try to change it?

Comment: @boboes It’s perfectly valid to use whatever subnet mask you want. Classful networking has long since been abandoned. Either way it won’t conflict with the 172.22/16 network.

Comment: @The_IT_Guy_You_Don't_Like - HOSTS file is default, which is empty. It just has the default sample comments.

Answer (score 0):

Route priority:

1. most specific match (smallest subnet that matches)
2. metric

Your routing table has an entry for `192.168.0.0` `255.255.0.0` on link, so it will send traffic destined for `192.168.5.118` directly via L2.

I don't think your trouble is routing.

- Could be DNS.
- Could be something else. Proxy settings on your browser with an address outside the 192.168.0.0/16 space would cause this.

Run wireshark and see where your traffic goes when you make a request to your `192.168.5.118` webserver.