# Setting network adapter priority no longer works in Windows 11

Tags: windows-11, network-adapter

I have two network adapters in a windows 11 computer: "Ethernet" and "Ethernet 2" (the first one is a Killer Ethernet controller, and the second a USB plug-in). "Ethernet 2" is a backup connection, has limited data, so by default (when it's working) I only want to use "Ethernet". Anyway, I had followed instructions similar to [these](https://%20https://superuser.com/a/709231/318722) and Windows was correctly prioritizing "Ethernet" for several years. However, about 6 months ago, I noticed (thanks to a big overage bill) that even when "Ethernet" was working fine, Windows was preferring "Ethernet 2". I re-did the steps (somehow "Ethernet 2" had become set to "automatic metric"). However, even though "Ethernet 2"'s interface metric is now set to 9999 and "Ethernet"'s interface metric is set to 1 as per screenshot below:

[image]

and I also did a route -f, and rebooted the computer, windows still prefers "Ethernet 2", as per the screenshot below ("Ethernet 2"'s usage is going up and not "Ethernet"; and "Ethernet 2" has a globe beside its "connected" label, which I assume means windows is using that adapter for internet access).

[image]

Edit: based on @Ramhound's comment, I also turned on metering for "Ethernet 2". Unfortunately, it didn't seem to make a difference, even after restarting the computer. See additional screenshot:

[image]

What else can I do to diagnose, and, more importantly, fix this?

Comment: Indicate that “Ethernet 2” is a metered connection.

Comment: @Ramhound Thanks, I tried that but it didn't seem to help

Answer (score 1):

I've seen the same behavior with Windows 10 and Windows 11.
Never found a good definitive fix, but there are a couple of things you could try.

My observations:

- Part of the problem seems to be the order in which the devices are initialized. Windows seems to favor the first 1.
  On 1 computer (onboard NIC + PCIe NIC, latter should have prio) I was able to fix the issue by moving the PCIe NIC to another slot (directly attached to CPU instead of behind a PCIe-PCIe bridge).
  So moving the Killer to another slot with higher prio (if possible) and/or the USB NIC to another USB port with lower prio might help.
- Lower speed interfaces get lower priority by default. If possible set the USB to 100 mb/s instead of Gigabit. (Bear in mind that Wifi 5 or 6 could be faster than 1 Gb/s and Windows may actually prefer the Wifi over a 1 Gb/s wired connection. I have seen that happen.)
- I'm not certain but I have a feeling that power-management may interact with this as well. If the driver for the NIC has a power-management setting try disabling that. (It will be enabled by default, if the setting is available.)

Please note: On a Windows Inplace Upgrade and sometimes on Windows Updates/Driver Updates Windows seems to have a tendency to reset the priority of NICs (and power-management settings) back to defaults/automatic, regardless of your preferences.
I've gotten in the habit of checking prio's (and resetting them) after every patch Tuesday.

Comment: The Killer network card is integrated into the motherboard

Comment: @Ramhound That's why I said "if possible". Most Killers are integrated, but there are variants as a PCIe  (or PCI for very early models) card as well.

Comment: @Tonny Thanks; both adapters have "all computer to turn off this device" and "allow this device to wake computer" checked, and "only allow magic packet to wake computer" unchecked. Which power setting for which adapter should I change to what?

Comment: @Tonny Also, how do change the speed of the USB port in windows 11?

Comment: @Tonny I tried plugging the USB adapter in different ports. The first time I tried that "Ethernet" remained connected to the internet so I thought that fixed it! But then I tried a different USB port, "Ethernet 2" had priority; and I plugged it back in the USB port where "Ethernet" had priority earlier, and it didn't work anymore; "Ethernet 2" now had priority. I could never get it to give "Ethernet" priority again :(

Comment: @Jimmy You don't change the speed of the USB port. You change the speed of the network card attached via USB. You may also have to change the speed on the switch-port to which the card connects. Setting one side manually and leaving the other end on auto-negotiate usually doesn't work very well. Both ends should be set manually to matching settings, or both be left on auto-negotiate.